# Alternative to globalizing arrays inside functions

Tags: php

I have many arrays that I'm constantly having to make global inside of functions like this

```
$siteSettings=/*some SQL work to make this array*/

function menuNav() {
    global $siteSettings;
    echo "Your site name is ".$siteSettings['name'];
}
menuNav();
```

I know I need to stop using "global" like this.  So I've come up with this alternate solution which is a lot easier for me to use, but uses $GLOBALS which I know isn't the best either.

```
function siteSettings($key) {
    //if the globals siteSettings array doesn't exist, make it
    if (!$GLOBALS['siteSettings']) /*some SQL work to make this array*/
    //return the value of this key
    return $GLOBALS['siteSettings'][$key];
}

function menuNav() {
    echo "Your site name is ".siteSettings('name');
}
menuNav();
```

Can you recommend - and show the code for - a better way of having the same array or object be used inside and outside of functions?

Also... please, do not suggest passing the array to the function like this menuNav($siteSettings).  The real functions I have set up are really complicated and use many different arrays like this one.  I wouldn't want to have to pass through a dozen different arrays every time I call a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a static public variable for this:

```
class Site
{
    public static $settings;
}
Site::$settings = /* SQL work */;
```

Then you can access it like:

```
function menuNav() {
    echo "Your site name is ".Site::$settings['name'];
}
```

Comment: Yes!  This is perfect!  I had asked THREE different questions about how to do this as a class.  Why couldn't anyone had just explain this as simply before!?!?!  Thank you!!!!